# Titanium backup history setting ignored

Tags: backup, titanium-backup, backup-manager

> Hello

I am a happy user of Titanium Backup, except for one thing. The maximum backup history is set to 1, a single backup, but over time, the backup folder now contains 88 backups. 
How can I make Titanium Backup only keep the most recent backup?

Screenshots are attached.

With kind regards,

Isaiah van Hunen

[image: Backup folder contains 88 backups] [image: Set to only one backup] [image: General information]

Comment: Max backup limit applies to per app backup. It does not act as a limit to the number of backup Titanium Backup would make overall. So you can technically have n backup of n individual apps but all of those apps would have a single backup for them at an individual level and that being the recent one. Is this what you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Firelord Would that means I would have 88 backups, each containing the latest app backup? Can I still limit my backups to only have one, the latest, backup at a time? Wouldn't that be logical and useful?

Comment: Isaiah, with *TiBu* you have one backup per app (plus one per system dataset such as WiFi APNs, call logs, SMS). So "one full backup" in your case might in fact result in 88 files. Perhaps the phrasing in the 1st screenshot is a bit misleading, it should better read "88 backup files" (Joël is no English native but French, it might have slipped him).

Comment: @Izzy Hi, thanks! So I do have the least amount of backup history? 88 backups is indeed misleading. What can now best be done to close this question? I suppose that if you post your comment as an answer, I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer

I'd say everything is working as expected, just your interpretation of the "88 backups" is wrong :)

#### Explanation

*Titanium Backup* doesn't make "one huge backup file covering all", but creates one set of backup files per app (usually 2 files: the `.apk` and the app settings as `.tar.gz`), plus one set per system data type (call logs, SMS, WiFi APNs, contacts, and such).

So the message "88 backups" is a bit misleading here: you should read that as "88 backup files" (which again would not be correct, as it rather means "88 objects" here; hard to find a proper term for this message: had you set a backup history limit of 2, and 2 of your apps had 2 backups, it would report "90 backups" here).

You can check this out yourself when investigating the backup directory using e.g. a file explorer: Navigate to `/storage/emulated/legacy/TitaniumBackup` (which should correspond with `sdcard/TitaniumBackup` and check the files therein. Naming convention is each file starts with the corresponding package name of the app, followed by either a time-stamp or a corresponding HEX string, and ends with either `.apk` or `.tar.gz`.

Comment: Always glad to help! *TiBu* was the first app I obtained the full version of right after rooting my first device. As at that time Joël couldn't offer it to be bought at *Google Play* (Switzerland wasn't in the "paid section" back then), I paid him with a "quick start manual" – so what you see [at TitaniumTrack](http://www.titaniumtrack.com/kb/titanium-backup-kb/titanium-backup-user-guide.html) was originally based on that :)

Comment: @Izzy Learn something new everyday :) I'm relation to your above comment

Comment: Yupp: Especially for starters, *TiBus* [knowledge base](http://www.titaniumtrack.com/kb/titanium-backup-kb) definitely is a recommended reading :)